# db2, with clause, variables and multiple join

Tags: join, db2, with-statement

I just cannot figure out how to use the nice technique of creating and using a variable like in the following example:

```
WITH t(myvar) AS (VALUES('welcome'))
SELECT tablename.*
FROM   tablename, t
WHERE  tablename.column1 = t.myvar
```

in a multi join query like this:

```
WITH t(myvar) AS (VALUES('welcomeagain'))
SELECT 
    tablename.*,
    joinedtable.valueid
FROM   
    tablename, t?
    left join joinedtable on
    joinedtable.keyid = tablename.keyid
WHERE  
    tablename.column1 = t.myvar
```

I mean, where, how and to what do I have to join the "t"? The environment is a DB2 ISeries 7.2.

Thank you very much for your help

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```sql
WITH t(myvar) AS (VALUES('welcomeagain'))
SELECT 
    tablename.*,
    t.myvar, 
    joinedtable.valueid
FROM   
    tablename
    join t on tablename.column1 = t.myvar
    left join joinedtable on joinedtable.keyid = tablename.keyid
```

or this

```sql
WITH t(myvar) AS (VALUES('welcomeagain'))
SELECT 
    tablename.*,
    t.myvar, 
    joinedtable.valueid
FROM   
    tablename
    left join t on tablename.column1 = t.myvar
    left join joinedtable on joinedtable.keyid = tablename.keyid
```

or this

```sql
WITH t(myvar) AS (VALUES('welcomeagain'))
SELECT 
    tablename.*,
    t.myvar, 
    joinedtable.valueid
FROM   
    tablename
    cross join t 
    left join joinedtable on joinedtable.keyid = tablename.keyid
```

What you don't want is the comma -- since that is an old style join and the syntax for combining that with the new style joins is always a little obtuse (if it works at all.)

Comment: @brosoft - I recommend trying the other options so you know which is most correct.